# Question about HOD

Tags: set-theory

Consider the full Solovay model $N=M[G]$ of set theory.
  Let HOD be the set of hereditarily ordinal definable elements of $M[G]$.
  It is known that in $N$ every set of reals definable from ordinals and reals is Baire measurable.

My question is:

In HOD, is every set definable from ordinals and reals (in HOD) Baire measurable?
  (i.e. is the property that a definable set is Baire measurable preserved by passage from $N$ to HOD?). If we consider also HOD(HOD) does the same remain true?

Edit: I rephrase my question to be: is there a model of set theory $M$ such that in HOD$^{M[G]}$ every set of reals definable from ordinals and reals is Baire measurable?
 Can we find a model of set theory in which HOD, HOD(HOD) etc.. all satisfy the same property above?

Answer (score 3):

There's not enough information in the question. If $M\models V=L$, then in $M$  we have that $\mathrm{HOD}^M=L^M=M$, and therefore $\mathrm{HOD}^{\mathrm{HOD}^M}=L^M=M$ as well.

In particular we have that in both instances sets of real definable from ordinals and reals (in $M$, which is the same as $\mathrm{HOD}^M$ in this case) are the same sets of reals in $L$, and so there are sets without the Baire property.

Comment: I know that HOD has sets that it thinks are not Baire measurable. My question is that in HOD, are definable sets Baire measurable?

Comment: And my point is that the question depends on more information. If $M\models V=L$ then $\mathrm{HOD}^M=M=L^M$. In that case, no. They don't have to have the Baire property.

Comment: Every inner model of $L$ is $L$. If $\mathrm{HOD}=L$, then you have $\mathrm{HOD(HOD)}=L$, and $\mathrm{HOD(HOD(HOD))}=L$ and $\mathrm{HOD(HOD(HOD(HOD)))}=L$, and so on and so forth. So nothing is different, and the answer is still negative to your question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: There are lots of wonderful papers about what can happen by iterating HOD.

Comment: @François: I know. None of which assume $\mathrm{HOD}=L$, though.

Comment: @Asaf: True, but that's one of the possibilities.

Comment: @François: And therefore further information is needed to properly answer this question. Especially since often in the context of Solovay's model, $M\models V=L$

Comment: Recall that we treat "Solovay models" as $L(\Bbb R)$ which satisfy certain axioms (Woodin has a nice axiomatization, if I recall correctly).

Comment: @François: My point was (and I apologize for the many pings) that the OP wrote "the full Solovay model" which is often takes place as $L[G]$ and its $\mathrm{HOD}$ is in fact $L$. So iterating $\mathrm{HOD}$s has no value. The question is now edited to reflect this, and the answer to that I do not know off hand.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, not really. In the context of large cardinals, $L(\mathbb R)$ of $V$ *is* a Solovay model. The standard meaning here is that the $L(\mathbb R)$ of $V$ is (perhaps in some forcing extension) elementary equivalent to the $L(\mathbb R)$ of $M[G]$ for some $M$ model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and some $G$ that is $M$-generic for the appropriate Levy collapse. In fact, what we have is an elementary embedding from such $L(\mathbb R)$ into the $L(\mathbb R)$ of $V$. Clearly, none of this is taking place in the neighborhood of $L$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila And the project of axiomatizing the Solovay model is not quite solved. Woodin has results indicating sufficient conditions for $L(\mathbb R)$ to be a Solovay model, but this is not the same. (Some of my work with Richard Ketchersid on natural model of determinacy grew out of the desire to understand what such an axiomatization would look like.)

Comment: @Andres: Thank you for this information (which I somehow missed on my inbox). In either case, I think that the OP's question is ill-posed. (Except the last edit)